# Flutter - Load full content page from network

Tags: flutter, dart

in my app there will be some content pages (about us, privacy policy,...) for which I don't want to hardcode the content, because it might change from time to time.

Since the text might contain some inline styles, headlines, paragraphs and links, I was wondering what the best practice to handle such pages might be.

1. Load the content (e.g. as json) from a network resource and live with the limitations: define headlines and paragraphs separately, no inline styles, so that you can properly fill predefined text widgets?
2. Is it possible to load the complete body code (widgets) for a page from an external resource? Is it ok in terms of performance?
3. Content will be written directly in the code - changes are only possible with an update of the app.

What's the best practice? Do you have some other ideas how to achieve flexibility without loosing performance?

Thanks already for your help!